# Things to consider before launching a BIG website?

Tags: web

I’m about to launch a classifieds website like gumtree and OLX in South Africa…., but it’s not gonna be as big as Gumtree or OLX obviously. It’s going to operate in one province…planning to expand it over time.

The site works like a charm on my local machine, but I’m concerned coz I’ve never launched a big website before.  Plus, I  just graduated from University this year – no work experience.  But I’m positive that if Facebook and Twitter were built by students, I too can build my own thing and run it successfully.

Are there any key issues to take into consideration before launching a big website ?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is scallable hosting.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you will require anything more than shared hosting...

Comment: shared hosting ? I heard it's not a good option for running a big website

Answer (score 0):

There is probably more to consider but I here are a few

1. Hire a lawyer and get a terms and conditions for your site with proper legality. You dont want to short yourself on this.
2. Get a decent backup and restore solution that you test and make sure that it works. Remember if you have paying clients with your site there will be implications for down time.
3. Get a security certificate `https://`
4. Know what you paying with your hosting solution. If your traffic does spike you could be in for a very large bill that you cant afford. And if you dont have scaling your site might run really slow. So get to know your hosting solution really well.
5. Good luck

Comment: interesting comment, 

much appreciated